# Elmah applicationName="myApplication" isn't working

Tags: elmah, application-name

I've found many posts about this issue, however I cannot find any resolution or even hints of where to start to make the "applicaitonName" attribute work. It still shows the Application column as a blank value. I've tried this with multiple projects and new projects and I get the same result. Elma logs everything else correctly but never with an application name.

Any ideas?

```
<elmah>
<security allowRemoteAccess="false" />
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="MyConnectionString" applicationName="MyApplication"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I just created a new database in SQL Server Express, ran the Elmah.SqlServer.sql creation script, created a new web project, installed the NuGet packages: ELMAH and elmah.sqlserver.

In web.config, ELMAH configuration looks like this:

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="elmah-sqlserver" applicationName="HelloWorld" />
```

When forcing 404 errors on the new website, new errors are logged to SQL Server express with HelloWorld in the application column.

Please be aware that the application name is not shown anywhere in the ELMAH UI (/elmah.axd). To see the application name, you should check the database or view the Raw/Source data in XML or in JSON through the errors details.